# Q-learning, state transition, immediate rewards (trading logic)

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, dqn

I've been thinking about how to correctly calculate rewards for several weeks now.

**Here is a grid example:**

```
##################################################################################
# | 0 | 1 | 2 |
---------------
0 |...|...|...|
1 |...|.A.|.G.|
2 |...|...|...|
##################################################################################
- the Agent(A) is currently at State(t) = [1,1]
- if he moves right -Goal(G)- he would get a Reward(t) of 100
- if the Agent(A) goes another way, he gets a Reward(t) of 0
- the selected Action(t) at State(t) depends ONLY on State(t) (no exploration)
- BUT the Reward(t) is calculated depending on State(t+1)?
- depending on Action(t) and based on State(t) we do the Transition to State(t+1)
##################################################################################
```

**Is that correct up to here?**

If not, then I have misunderstood something and therefore I am not making progress. I try to implement the whole thing in a trading logic, I am not sure if I am doing it right.

**Imagine a simple time series and 3 Actions (B=BUY/H=HOLD/C=CLOSE):**

```
# 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 . . . . . . . . . 19 (index/position)
##################################################################################
# 1 3 5 8 7 9 2 3 6 4 . . . . . . . . . 8  (data/value/price)
# . . B H H C . . . . . . . . . . . . . done
#    t^ buy open
##################################################################################
```

The Agent opens a BUY on Index(t)=2 at Price(t)=5, the Reward(t) is 8(t+1) - 5(t) = 3. I open a trade on State(t), the Reward(t) depends on the next value(t+1)?

**Is that correct?**

And if i close the trade? The next value doesn't matter, as I'm closing the trade at the current Price(t)?

In the examples here, the difference(entry.price - exit.price) is used, which is very confusing:

https://github.com/miroblog/deep_rl_trader/blob/master/TraderEnv.py#L94

https://github.com/edwardhdlu/q-trader/blob/master/train.py#L36

I see 2 problems, the drawdown while holding the positions is ignored and the sparse rewards are more difficult to learn, what do you think?

**Thanks in advance!**

---

**EDIT: The main question is:**

In a grid world, the Action(t) is done at State(t), **BUT** the Reward(t) depends on the next State(t+1), because only if this is the goal, it gets a reward.

In a trading environment, i can find a lot of different versions, some guys are using future values, some are using the difference of entry/exit/current close price or other stuff like sharpe/sortino/...

What is correct in a trading environment and why?

or

How do i calculate the rewards for a trading bot?

Comment: There is a lot of thing in your post. Would you mind to try to make it more specific ? (also you might want to post this kind of question on the quant stack exchange)